# Is it possible to prove the Duality Principle in classical propositional logic without using Contraposition?

Tags: logic

The Duality Principle to the effect that if $A\vDash B$, then $B^*\vDash A^*$, where $\alpha^*$ is dual to $\alpha$, can easily be proven by Substitution and Contraposition (Antony Eagle, *Elements of Deductive Logic*, p. 88). But is it possible to prove it without Contraposition (namely, the principle to the effect that if $A\vDash B$, then $\neg B\vDash \neg A$)?

Comment: To prove Duality you need De Morgan's Laws: thus Double Negation, Contraposition or some other principle equivalent to LEM.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your comment. Does it mean it is possible to prove the Duality Principle in a way that does not explicitly rely on Contraposition (by using some other law)?